# Format response array into a POST request

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Not sure how to ask this or how to word it the best, so my apologies in advance, especially if this is a duplicate.

I get an array in response to a GET request that I make towards an API.
It's a list of customers. It has their email and ID.
That response looks like this:

[image: Array Response]

The app has another endpoint, at which I can add customers to a certain list.
I'd like to know how to take that array response, and (obviously automatically and no matter the number) convert it into:

[image: this format of a POST request]

I'm just not that far yet to know a solution to this. I'm guessing some kind of a loop, but I don't know how to loop over results, nor how to separate them one by one...

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
let profiles = [];
$.each(records, function(i, data){
   profiles.push({email: data.email})
});
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'enpoint url here',
   data: {
      api_key: 'your key here',
      profiles: profiles
   },
   success: function(response){
      // do stuff with the api response
   }
});
```